# Async Confirmation Dialog in Vue 3 with composition api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm fairly new to Vue, and I wanted to create an async confirmation dialog. I was trying to adapt some code i've seen on a website:

**ConfirmDialog.Vue**

```
(...)
        <v-btn
          v-if="!options.noconfirm"
          color="grey"
          text
          class="body-2 font-weight-bold"
          @click.native="cancel"
          >Cancel</v-btn
        >
        <v-btn
          color="primary"
          class="body-2 font-weight-bold"
          outlined
          @click.native="agree"
          >OK</v-btn
        >
(...)
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "ConfirmDlg",
    data() {
      return {
        dialog: false,
        resolve: null,
        reject: null,
        message: null,
        title: null,
        options: {
          color: "grey lighten-3",
          width: 400,
          zIndex: 200,
          noconfirm: false,
        },
      };
    },

    methods: {
      open(title, message, options) {
        this.dialog = true;
        this.title = title;
        this.message = message;
        this.options = Object.assign(this.options, options);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.resolve = resolve;
          this.reject = reject;
        });
      },
      agree() {
        this.resolve(true);
        this.dialog = false;
      },
      cancel() {
        this.resolve(false);
        this.dialog = false;
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

**Component using the confirm dialog**

```
<template>
  <!-- other code -->
  <ConfirmDlg ref="confirm" />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    components: {
      ConfirmDlg: () => import("./ConfirmDlg"),
    },
    methods: {
      async delRecord() {
        if (
          await this.$refs.confirm.open(
            "Confirm",
            "Are you sure you want to delete this record?"
          )
        ) {
          this.deleteRecord();
        }
      },
      deleteRecord() {
        console.log("Record deleted.");
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

I'm trying to adapt this code to composition api, but i'm struggling with the promise part:

```
const open = ref(false)

const resolve = ref();
const reject = ref();

const agree = () =>{
  resolve.value= true;
  open.value = false;
}

const cancel = () => {
  resolve.value= false;
  open.value = false;
}


const open = () => {
  open.value = true;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  // this is the part i struggle
        resolve = resolve;
        reject = reject;
  });
}
```

Dialog is opening but the promise part is not working properly, it seems to resolve immediately. Anyone has any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Please, post https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve instead of truncated snippets. It's unknown what is the context for the second snippet. Here you don't call `resolve` so it's impossible for it to resolve immediately or else. `  resolve.value= false;
  open.value = false` - this is a mistake. These values are ]supposed to be callback functions, not booleans, check the original code. `resolve = resolve` - this doesn't make sense, don't call params the same way as variables from parent scope if you don't intend to shadow them

Comment: Sorry for the snippets, i was trying to focus more on the options api -> composition api transition. You pointed exactly to the issue, if i create `const resolve = ref()` it doesn't let me use it like the code above `this.resolve(true)` and when he does 'this.resolve = resolve' he seems to be assigning the state variable `resolve` to the callback function, but i struggle with translating this to the composition. Thank you for taking the time, even though my question is messy

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. I can not explain why, but it's work for me.

```
const open = ref(false);

let confirmResolve = { (value: boolean): void } = () => { /* do nothing */ }

const agree = () => {
  confirmResolve(true);
  open.value = false;
}

const cancel = () => {
  confirmResolve(false);
  open.value = false;
}


const open = (): Promise<boolean> => {
  open.value = true;

  return new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {
        confirmResolve = resolve;
  });
}
```